# Available diskspace on MacOsx

Tags: bash, macos, diskspace

i want to write a script to download and restore a database on local machines.
Is it possible to write a check in bash that just checks if there are more than 40gb of space on the device?

I tried it with df -h but the output doesnt seem useable.
Maybe there is something iam missing with awk/sed?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`df` is a must. But the `-h` flag may be bad for this purpose.

```
TARGET= # your target path here
BLOCKS=$(df "$TARGET"| awk 'NR==2{print $4}')
SIZE_FREE=$((BLOCKS * 1024))
```

This gives the result you want. Result is `$SIZE_FREE` bytes.